# Ranking by partition in visual foxpro

Tags: sql, visual-foxpro, dense-rank

I have the following table that looks like

```
+ --- + --- +
| AID | Tag |
+ --- + --- +
| 1   | 1   |
| 2   | 2   |
| 2   | 3   |
| 2   | 820 |
| 2   | 821 |
| 3   | 2   |
| 4   | 5   |
| 4   | 18  |
| 4   | 2744|
| 4   | 2745|
+ --- + --- +
```

When I write the following SQL Server 2008 code

```
select AID,
       Tag,
       RANK() over (partition by AID order by Tag asc) as rank
from My_Table
```

it produces the following results

```
+ --- + --- + ---- +
| AID | Tag | Rank |
+ --- + --- + ---- +
| 1   | 1   | 1    |
| 2   | 2   | 1    |
| 2   | 3   | 2    |
| 2   | 820 | 3    |
| 2   | 821 | 4    |
| 3   | 2   | 1    |
| 4   | 5   | 1    | 
| 4   | 18  | 2    |
| 4   | 2744| 3    |
| 4   | 2745| 4    |
+ --- + --- + ---- +
```

which is exactly what I want.

Now, I want to write the same thing in Visual FoxPro 9 SQL. I tried it using *recno()* as demonstrated [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8918a5f3-b512-4ca2-b0fb-d8a9b73072e3/rank-foxpro-7?forum=visualfoxprogeneral); this numbers my records, but doesn't seem to support the ability to partition, and correlated subqueries don't seem to be supported in VFP 9 SQL. I know that I could do this with cursors and scans, but I don't want to do it that way. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not use stored procedures in sql server instead? I doubt that VFP is going to support windowed functions as that language has not had an update in over a decade and MS is no longer supporting or making upgrades.

Comment: Would love to move the entire system over to SQL. But I'm not in charge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the answer, for anyone who cares to know. The following SQL code is supported in Visual FoxPro 9.0 and will do what we want.

```
select  t1.aid, ;
        t1.tag, ;
        count(*) as rank ;
    from my_table t1 ;
    inner join my_table t2 ;
        on t2.aid = t1.aid ;
        and t2.tag <= t1.tag ;
    group by t1.aid, t1.tag
```

To see why, let's take a closer look at the inner join by leaving out the aggregate and including the tags from *t2*.

```
select  t1.aid, ;
        t1.tag, ;
        t2.tag ;
    from my_table t1 ;
    inner join my_table t2 ;
        on t2.aid = t1.aid ;
        and t2.tag <= t1.tag ;
    order by t1.aid, t1.tag
```

This code produces a table like

```
+ --- + ---- + ---- +
| AID | Tag1 | Tag2 |
+ --- + ---- + ---- +
| 1   | 1    | 1    |
| 2   | 2    | 2    |
| 2   | 3    | 2    |
| 2   | 3    | 3    |
| 2   | 820  | 2    |
| 2   | 820  | 3    |
| 2   | 820  | 820  |
| 2   | 821  | 2    |
| 2   | 821  | 3    |
| 2   | 821  | 820  |
| 2   | 821  | 821  |
| 3   | 2    | 2    |
| 4   | 5    | 5    | 
| 4   | 18   | 5    |
| 4   | 18   | 18   |
| 4   | 2744 | 5    |
| 4   | 2744 | 18   |
| 4   | 2744 | 2744 |
| 4   | 2745 | 5    |
| 4   | 2745 | 18   |
| 4   | 2745 | 2744 |
| 4   | 2745 | 2745 |
+ --- + ---- + ---- +
```

We don't actually care about the data in *Tag2*, but now we can clearly see that the rank is the count of the *Tag1* grouped by *Aid* and *Tag1*.

Answer (score 1):

In VFP there is not a rank() function. However, you can achieve the same effect in a number of ways. One way is simple scan...endscan pass updating the ranking value as in the following example:

```
*** Sample Data
    Create Cursor mytable ( AID Int, Tag Int)
    Insert Into mytable Values (1,1   )
    Insert Into mytable Values (2,2   )
    Insert Into mytable Values (2,3   )
    Insert Into mytable Values (2,820 )
    Insert Into mytable Values (2,821 )
    Insert Into mytable Values (3,2   )
    Insert Into mytable Values (4,5   )
    Insert Into mytable Values (4,18  )
    Insert Into mytable Values (4,2744)
    Insert Into mytable Values (4,2745)
*** Sample Data

Select AID, Tag, Cast(0 As Int) As rank ;
    from mytable ;
    order By AID, Tag ;
    into Cursor crsRanked ;
    readwrite

Scan
    AID = AID
    rcno = Recno()
    Replace rank With Recno()-m.rcno+1 While AID = m.AID
    Skip -1
Endscan

Locate
Browse
```

EDIT: Yesterday I overlooked how MS SQL server's RANK() function work, sorry. Here is one that work like MS SQL Server's Rank(), Dense_Rank(), Row_number():

```
Create Cursor mytable ( AID Int, Tag Int)
Insert Into mytable Values (1,1   )
Insert Into mytable Values (2,2   )
Insert Into mytable Values (2,3   )
Insert Into mytable Values (2,820 )
Insert Into mytable Values (2,821 )
Insert Into mytable Values (3,2   )
Insert Into mytable Values (4,5   )
Insert Into mytable Values (4,18  )
Insert Into mytable Values (4,18  )
Insert Into mytable Values (4,18  )
Insert Into mytable Values (4,2744)
Insert Into mytable Values (4,2745)

Select AID, Tag, ;
    Cast(0 As Int) As rownum, ;
    Cast(0 As Int) As rank, ;
    Cast(0 As Int) As denserank ;
    from mytable ;
    order By AID, Tag ;
    into Cursor crsRanked ;
    readwrite

Local AID,rank,denserank,nextrank,rcno
Scan
    AID = AID
    rank = 0
    nextrank = 0
    denserank = 0
    rcno = Recno()
    Scan While m.AID = AID
        Tag = Tag
        rank = nextrank + 1
        denserank = m.denserank + 1
        Replace ;
            rank With m.rank, ;
            denserank With m.denserank, ;
            rownum With Recno()-m.rcno+1 ;
            While AID = m.AID And Tag = m.Tag
        nextrank = m.nextrank + _Tally
        Skip -1
    Endscan
    Skip -1
Endscan

Locate
Browse
```

Comment: This is really well written code! Thanks for taking the time to answer, but I was looking for a solution that did not involve scans.